# New Firebase connection to Flutter application not connecting

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I just created a new flutter application and trying to connect a newly made firebase Firestore. Cli has been added and flutterfire config has been ran.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError){
          print('Error');
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
          return const MyHomePage(title: 'WOWZA',);
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

When breaking at the if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) is says connectionState is .none and unsure as to why.

Can anyone help?

Comment: i think you need to add a future to your FutureBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing future initialization -

From:

```html
home: FutureBuilder(builder: ((context, snapshot) {

    if(snapshot.hasError){
      print('Error');
    }
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
      return const MyHomePage();
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
  )
  )
```

To:

```html
home: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initialization,
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError){
          print('Error');
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
          return const MyHomePage();
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code with this snippet.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
  ),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError){
          print('Error');
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
          return const MyHomePage(title: 'WOWZA',);
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      )
      )
    );
  }
}
```